# Retaining calculated jQuery totals after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using `jQuery` and `ASP.NET MVC 3` with the `razor view engine`.

I have a couple of textboxes in which numeric values can be typed.  I have a label control that has the totals of the textboxes calculated by jQuery.

I have the following textboxes and label (for the calculated results):

```
<input id="GrossMonthlySalary" type="text" />
<input id="SpouseGrossMonthlySalary" type="text" />
<input id="AdditionalIncome" type="text" />
<input id="ChildSupportIncome" type="text" />

<label id="TotalMonthlyIncome" class="total-amount"></label>
```

In my .js file I have the following:

```
$(function () {

   $('#GrossMonthlySalary, #SpouseGrossMonthlySalary, #AdditionalIncome, #ChildSupportIncome').keyup(function () {
      var val1 = $('#GrossMonthlySalary').val();
      var val2 = $('#SpouseGrossMonthlySalary').val();
      var val3 = $('#AdditionalIncome').val();
      var val4 = $('#ChildSupportIncome').val();

      var totalMonthlyIncome =
         (parseInt(val1, 10) || 0) +
         (parseInt(val2, 10) || 0) +
         (parseInt(val3, 10) || 0) +
         (parseInt(val4, 10) || 0);

      if (totalMonthlyIncome == 0) {
         $('#TotalMonthlyIncome').text('');
      }
      else {
         $('#TotalMonthlyIncome').text(totalMonthlyIncome);
      }
   });
});
```

If I click on my submit button and there are errors then the errors are displayed and the my label control with the calculated results are cleared.  How do I retain the values after post back?

Just another question on the way that I calculated the results, is this good or is there a better way?

Comment: The errors on the submitted form are coming from ASP, you need to show the ASP code/errors. You're too vauge. Also, don't cut+paste+tweak stuff, it's *bad*, use an array. Val1 val2 val3 is awful code and what arrays are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that parseInt will fail the second it hits a non numeric character:

```
parseInt('$10') // NaN
```

As far as calculating the total, since you aren't doing any additional processing for specific values, you could simplify the whole thing by using a class selector.

```
$('.incomes').keyup(function () {

  var incomes = $('.incomes'),
      totalDisplay = $('#TotalMonthlyIncome'),
      totalVal = 0;

  incomes.each(function() {
      var matches = null;
      // find the number to add to total
      matches = $(this).val().match(/\d+/);
      // not bothering with the regex on totalVal because we set it
      totalVal = ( matches !== null ? parseInt(matches[0],10) : 0 ) + parseInt(totalVal,10);
  });
  totalVal = totalVal === 0 ? '' : totalVal;
  totalDisplay.text(totalVal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I retain the calculated values after postback?

Comment: Does the class have to be defined in my stylesheet?  With what styles?

Comment: The class doesn't haven't to be defined in your stylesheet. It is just a way to easily grab multiple DOM Nodes, because IDs have to be unique. As far as retaining the values goes, I am not an ASP.NET guy, but the basic concept is that you post the data in the inputs to a controller, set those values for the view, and in your view you should be able to set <input value="{GrossMonthlySalary}" />

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code looks just fine. I can shorten it a little ( http://jsfiddle.net/JBqRj/4 ), but it doesn't actually optimize anything.

If you want to post it to the server, then you should just need to add a hidden text field to your form containing the same value as your label: http://jsfiddle.net/JBqRj/5/

In order to retain the posted values following the error, though, you need to do that within your ASP code. Just have it fill the form fields (including the hidden field) with the same ones that were posted.

Comment: That's generally bad practice. Try and add in another twenty lines in there, what happens?

Comment: @mblase: I'm not that worried about posting the totals to the server, it's just to display to the user while typing in the values.

Comment: @Incognito: What is bad practice?

Comment: @Incognito: Then give a solution instead of being critical :)

Comment: @Brendan Vogt I told you, use arrays. http://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+array+tutorial